# How can I solve error in obfuscating Dll?

Tags: obfuscar

when I try to obfuscate a dll developed with Visual Studio, I get this error message:

> An error occurred during processing:
>   Failed to get type definitions for CreoParamLm, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4e4fd84ef410cf6
>   Cannot clean pool

I didn't find any info searching with Google for this typology of error, do you have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's any help, that error message is [from obfuscar's setup code](https://github.com/obfuscar/obfuscar/blob/master/Obfuscar/AssemblyInfo.cs). It looks like there should be errors logged somewhere, which might be useful.

Comment: Thanks AakashM but the obfuscated Dll never is created. So I cannot read the usual file Mapping.txt.

Comment: https://github.com/obfuscar/obfuscar/blob/784529c9d67a8bb16ec023237b3f1562e2cb0f0c/Obfuscar/AssemblyInfo.cs#L514 Obfuscar writes what's wrong to stderr before throwing that exception. Thus, you should check what it says above this line.